# I cannot get 'show faces' to work in the like box

Tags: helper, facebook-likebox

I am stumped - I have been spending hours trying to get what I thought would be something simple to work, I have failed.

Go to the following URL:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

Replace 'platform' in the Facebook Page URL text box  with my page 'thenetipot.net'

You will see I have 411 likes, yet no faces show up, even though 'Show Faces' is selected. Try any other page and they all show faces, but not mine! The only way I have got any to show is by changing the height to 1000 which is no way any sort of resolution?

Please help and happy new year!

Answer (score 1):

I think it will only show faces of friends of currently logged user.