# Facebook Like Box is Broke

Tags: facebook-likebox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I cannot get 'show faces' to work in the like box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660295/i-cannot-get-show-faces-to-work-in-the-like-box)

Go to the like box app page:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

Put in my profile:

http://www.facebook.com/thenetipot.net

Hit return to generate the new preview.

Turn off stream. Leave faces as shown.

You will note no faces are shown.

Now change the height to 500 and hit return to generate again - some now start to show up! You can increase it from there to 600, 700, 800 but the box is to big then and you can never get the wrap to work out neatly.

The other thing noted is if I login to my facebook user account with the standard height  (not the page owner account) - I see 3 friends show up in the like box, so perhaps there is some sort of security profile thing going on?

But I don't know what privacy setting that could be, as put in anyone else's URL and you will see the box neatly displayed with 10 people shown who will not be direct friends of your facebook account e.g. as with the following n the app URL box /smartpassiveincome

Answer (score 1):

You've posted this question three times now. I would suggest that if the canned plugin that Facebook freely provides is not working out for you, to hire a developer to use the APIs to create your one that works to your needs. Make sure you have purchased a support package from that developer so in case you need any tweaks done after it is built or if facebook changes their API breaking your code (happens all the time).